# How to begin committing via git to bitbucket - Not seeing changes

Tags: git, version-control

Perhaps I am going about this wrong, but I am following git tutorials as is.  I have a repository on bitbucket called "testrepos" and I am trying to work with it.

First, I clone it with `git clone https://my_username@bitbucket.org/my_username/testrepos.git`

Now, the repo is empty, so I made a file called main.cpp.  I then run "git add main.cpp".  If I run `git status` now, I see that there is a new file called main.cpp to be committed.

Finally, I run `git commit -m 'First commit'`.  There are 0 changes, 0 insertions, and 0 deletions!  Why are my files not committing?  I am using `push` and `pull` as well.

**edit** Here is the full log:

```
Welcome to Git (version 1.7.7-preview20111014)

Run 'git help git' to display the help index.
Run 'git help <command>' to display help for specific commands.

chris@EDI ~
$ cd git

chris@EDI ~/git
$ git clone https://my_username@bitbucket.org/my_username/testrepos.git
Cloning into testrepos...
Password:
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

chris@EDI ~/git
$ cd testrepos/

chris@EDI ~/git/testrepos (master)
$ git pull
Password:
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.

chris@EDI ~/git/testrepos (master)
$ git add temp.cpp

chris@EDI ~/git/testrepos (master)
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   temp.cpp
#

chris@EDI ~/git/testrepos (master)
$ git commit -m 'Committing temp file'
[master (root-commit) 5d659df] Committing temp file
 Committer: unknown <chris@EDI.(none)>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author

 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 temp.cpp

chris@EDI ~/git/testrepos (master)
$ git pull
Password:
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.

chris@EDI ~/git/testrepos (master)
$ git push
Password:
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: Don't you need to push and pull to get data in and out of repo's?

Comment: Please post a full log of all of the commands that you use, from the first "git pull", including cd commands, etc.

Comment: @Mark Hildreth I've posted the full log of all commands.  Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You really do need to do `git push origin master`, rather than just `git push`.  This is because the default behaviour of `git push` is to push each branch to one with the same name on the remote side, *so long as a remote branch with that name exists*.  In this case, your BitBucket repository is completely empty (without a `master` branch, since there are no commits) so no branches will be pushed by the default behaviour of `git push` or `git push origin`.  Your push will work if you do:

```
git push origin master
```

... but since this is your first push, you should do:

```
git push -u origin master
```

... which also sets the `master` branch in `origin` to be the default upstream branch for your `master` branch.  You only need to use this form of the command once.

Comment: +1 because it explains WHY you have to do `git push origin master` once.

Comment: +1 because of the explanation.  github didn't have this same requirement for the initial push.

Answer (score 3):

Try `git push origin master`.

Answer (score 1):

Was the file you added empty? The message is showing you the number of changes files, and the number of lines inserted and deleted. If you just added an empty file, git doesn't count that as "changed" in the numbers it's generating. It DOES, however, commit the file.

Try to push back up to bitbucket, and view the repository file listing in a web browser. You should see your file there.

Comment: This is my problem.  Even if I try "git push" afterwards, I'm not seeing any commits to the repo in the web browser.  "No commits recorded yet."

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue as well, and I have seen a lot of unhelpful advice. Finally, I broke down and read the code for git-pull and git-fetch. In my case, the problem is caused by having "**tagopt = --tags**" in the configuration file for the remote in question. This seems to cause git-fetch to do "automated tag following" which has a bad side-effect of truncating the FETCH_HEAD file in some cases. This in turn causes git-pull to fail with the error:

> Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'master'
>   from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.

I am really not confident enough with the internals of git to say if this is a bug or intended behavior or just me not understanding git very well. However, removing "**tagopt**" settings from my config files has solved the problem for me in all instances.

Note, this is particularly confusing because manually running "git fetch --tags ..." takes a different code path and FETCH_HEAD is left in good shape.

(I am running git version 1.7.4.1)

Answer (score 0):

> git push -u origin --all

for first time

> git push origin --all

afterwards

is whats listed on bitbucket 101

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Create+a+repository